# Procs From "Understanding Ruby Blocks, Procs, and Lambdas" Article

Tags: ruby, lambda, proc

Ok, reviewing Procs, lambdas, and blocks via this [link](http://web.archive.org/web/20081222144552/http://www.robertsosinski.com/2008/12/21/understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-lambdas/).

Question on this code:

```
class Array
  def iterate!
    self.each_with_index do |n, i|
      self[i] = yield(n)
    end
  end
end


array = [1, 2, 3, 4]

array.iterate! do |n|
  n ** 2
end

puts array.inspect
```

Conceptually, I understand almost everything, except one line which is this:

`self[i] = yield(n)`

I get that this self in this line `self.each_with_index do |n, i|` means that it's a class method, right?

But why do we need to assign the parameters in `yield(n)` to `self[i]`?

Please explain in super basic way if you can.

(in other words, please be nice - which people generally are for most part here - just a little extra nervous that I'm not getting this which is making me feel stupid)

Answer (score 0):

The method is `iterate!`, which is an instance method. `self` in `self.each_with_index` is the receiver of the method [Enumerable#each_with_instance](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html). Since `self` is the current instance of `Array` (`[1,2,3,4]` in your example), `self.` is not needed; i.e., you could (and imo, should) just write `each_with_index do |n, i|...`. In other words, `self` is the implied receiver when no explicit receiver is specified.

Regarding the line:

```
self[i] = yield(n)
```

for your example `array = [1,2,3,4]` your enumerator is:

```
enum = [1,2,3,4].each_with_index
  #=> #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3, 4]:each_with_index>
```

with elements

```
enum.to_a
  #=> [[1, 0], [2, 1], [3, 2], [4, 3]]
```

The first element passed into block by `Array#each` is therefore `[1,0]`, which is assigned to the block variables:

```
n = 1
i = 0
```

resulting in

```
self[0] = yield(1) => 1**2 => 1
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to explain in a super basic way.

> I get that this self in this line `self.each_with_index do |n, i|` means
>   that it's a class method, right?

Nope. The meaning of `self` depends on the context. If `self` was in the class, it would refer to the class. But here `self` is in an instance method, so it refers to the instance (so `each_with_index` is also an instance method).

> But why do we need to assign the parameters in `yield(n)` to `self[i]`?

The goal of `iterate!` is to modify the array in place. Since `self` refers to the instance, `self[i]` accesses the elements of the array that `iterate!` is being called on, thus modifying the array in place.

Also, I'm not sure what you mean by "parameters" here. `yield(n)` passes `n` to the block, runs the block, and returns the value.

Answer (score 0):

`self[i] = yield(n)` reassigns the values in the array, to the block that was specified in

```
array.iterate! do |n|
  n ** 2
end
```

which basically means, take the value of the array, and square it, save that value in the element of the array. So `[1, 2, 3 , 4]` becomes `[1 ** 2, 2 ** 2, 3 ** 2, 4 ** 2] => [2, 4, 9, 16]`

Answer (score 0):

Self changes with(and actually is) the current context or surrounding object.

Since

```
self.each_with_index do |n, i|
...
```

is monkey patching the Array class and is within an instance method `iterate!`, self refers to the instance itself: in this case the array `[1, 2, 3, 4]`.

You're probably thinking of this:

```
class some_class

  def self.a_class_method
  ...
```

which is defined in the context of a class. So self is the class itself(which is also an object), not an instance of that class.

Since self is just the array `[1, 2, 3, 4]`

```
self[i] = yield(n)
```

is replacing each element of the array with results of the sent in block.

Answer (score 0):

Here iterate! is an instance function of Array class and you have an array object.When you do

```
array.iterate! do |n|
n ** 2
end
```

You are passing a block 'do |n| n**2 end' to iterate! function.In the function you can access this block using yield.But as you can see block is expecting one parameter through |n| so you need to pass one parameter and the block code will return the square of it.

```
self[i] = yield(n)
```

self is being used in Array instance context.So it is modifying the values of array.

For more information please check this article:

http://geekdirt.com/blog/blocks-lambda-and-procs-in-ruby/